# How to perform animation on the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-animation, toolbar

I have two fragments and i have also added a toolbar in the main activity that has the container for these fragments. What i am doing is that I am applying animations such that one fragment is replaced by the other.

I also have a toolbar which is hidden in the first fragment but displayed in the second one. the animation works fine but I don't understand how can i use the same animation to the toolbar so that the toolbar appears to be the part of the second fragment.

here is my code for the main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   // setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   /* actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logohome);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.hide();*/

   toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logohome);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_container);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, new Splash(), null).commit();

    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, new Splash());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
                    setCustomAnimations(R.anim.transition, R.anim.splashanimation).
                    add(R.id.main_container, new Login() ).commit();
            //fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
    },3000);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is also a view you can use  `toolbar.setAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());`

```
 public Animation inFromRightAnimation()
    {
        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        inFromRight.setDuration(240);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
    }
```

This show it load from next screen